# Pre-loaded SD: Is Raspbian installed?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I just bought a new Raspberry Pi 3 and a pre-loaded sd card with Raspbian. I turned the Pi on and I'm not sure if the raspbian is installed. I didn't have any window to choose an option to install. Like in all the guides show. I do see the Pi logo at the center of the screen, and a toolbar at the top, including some web browser.

Should I download NOOBS and install it, or is Raspbian is already installed?

Comment: It's already installed. You got full-working system.

Answer (score 1):

A *pre-loaded* card means that it came with Raspbian already installed. What you see when you hook the Raspberry Pi up to a screen and power it on is the desktop. It's similar to the LXDE desktop found in lubuntu.